# Save object created in onRender() function in htmlWidgets

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, plotly, htmlwidgets

I am using the onRender() function from the htmlWidgets package within a Shiny application. I am trying to save certain objects that I create within a given onRender() function call so that they can be used outside of that given onRender() function call.

Below is my MWE. I am creating an object called val2 in the onRender() function, which is simply the slider input value multiplied by 2. Can I save the val2 object so that it can be used later outside of the onRender() function? (I realize that I do not need to use the onRender() function to create the val2 object in this over-simplified example, but I am trying to keep the example simple).

Thank you for any advice!

```
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shiny)

myPlot <- qplot(data=mtcars, mpg, cyl)
gMyPlot <- ggplotly(myPlot)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sliderInput("ci", "Value:", min = 0, max = 1, value=0.95, step=0.01),
  plotlyOutput("myTest")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  ci <- reactive(input$ci)

  output$myTest <- renderPlotly(gMyPlot %>% onRender("
                  function(el, x, data) {
                  val2 = data * 2
                  console.log(val2)
                  }", data=ci()))})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Any feedback for me?

Comment: Thank you; very helpful! It seems to be working on my real problem (not just MWE), so I don't think I have any coding questions right now. As a concept, when you note that it is inefficient to have values going back and forth between the server and client, do you believe this is particularly problematic in certain situations (large data sets, etc.)? It seems to be working pretty fast for me, but I would be grateful to know if there could be certain applications in which this would be so inefficient it would start to jeopardize performance? Thank you again.

Comment: If you were passing a large data structures over a narrow pipe from your shinyServer to your client, it could definitely be a problem. But if you are just using it on a PC, or even just over a LAN, I wouldn't worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does that. I modified your example to make it slightly more interactive. Then I store the "val2" value twice using javascript, once in an  h3 tag (which I got working first), and then in as an element of the reactive `input` list (which is more useful of course). Note that this does not seem very efficient as the values are going back and forth between the server and the client.

Here is the code:

```
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$h3('',class ='val2'),
  sliderInput("ci", "Value:", min = 0, max = 34, value=34, step=1),
  plotlyOutput("myPlot"),
  textOutput("outval2")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  ci <- reactive(input$ci)

  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly({
            mdf <- mtcars %>% filter(mpg<ci())
            myPlot <- qplot(data=mdf, mpg, cyl)
            ggplotly(myPlot) %>% onRender("function(el, x, data) {
                                            val2 = data * 2
                                            console.log(val2)
                                            $('h3.val2').text('val2:'+val2);
                                            Shiny.onInputChange('val2', val2);
                                            }", data=ci())
            })
  output$outval2 <- renderPrint({sprintf("The calculated value is:%d",input$val2)})
  }
)
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And here is a screen shot of the working app:

[image]

A relevent post worth reading is this: [Sending Shiny data from client to server](https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/)